# Populating a custom ASP.NET DDL Server Control

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

I am creating a simple server control which inherits from System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList. This DDL will be populated by a list of languages.

I want to know on what event I should populate the DDL with the list from the Database.

OnLoad, OnInit or maybe in the constructor of the class? Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always create and initialize dynamic server controls on Init page event.

As explicitly stated here ("Use this event to read or initialize control properties") :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

also this is a reccomended read :

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

[ASP.NET Web Server Control Event Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3bwdsh3.aspx)

http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx

Comment: I see what you have read, however, on the same page it says 'Use the OnLoad event method to set properties in controls and to establish database connections.' is this for something else?

Comment: Yeah, I see that, but if you wont viewstate to work, you must populate controls in init